# After Opening My Minecraft World to LAN, How Can My Friends Join? (Minecraft Java Edition)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I opened my Minecraft singleplayer world to LAN so that my friend could join, but we don't know how she can join my world directly. How can this be done?

Comment: The wiki tells you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're aware, so I'll let you know here, if she is not on the same network as you, she will not be able to connect unless you port forward. I cannot provide help on port forwarding, as I don't know the model of your router.

If you are on the same network, you can try opening the 'Multiplayer' tab from the main menu and seeing if it shows up there. If it doesn't show up under this, here are some steps to figure out what your address is on your local network.

---

**Windows:**

1. Open the command line (In the Start Menu, type "Command Prompt" and open it)
2. In the command line type `ipconfig | findstr "IPv4"`

Something like this should show up:

[image: ipconfig output]

You'll want to enter the number at the end of your output, including the periods, into the 'Direct Connect' prompt under the 'Multiplayer' tab in minecraft.

---

I'm afraid I'm not very versed in Linux, but here's a stackoverflow post that may help: ["How to get the primary IP address of the local machine on Linux and OS X?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x)

---

If you aren't on the same network, you'll need to port forward, instructions per router can be found on [this website.](https://portforward.com/)

Once you've port forwarded, go to [this website.](https://www.whatismyip.com/) to get your public IP address, and enter this into the 'Direct Connect' prompt.

Answer (score 0):

On the other device, go to multiplayer and the world should pop up below where it says: "Scanning for games on your local network."
[image]

If it does not come up, you may have to manually enter the game address by going to "Direct Connect"